# charset issue with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to store the following line in mysql:

```
$data = "After 30μs, what fraction of the charge will remain?"
```

If I display $data on HTML Page I get the exact text but if i store this in database then i get this data on output I get the following :

```
After 30Î?s, what fraction of the charge will remain?
```

I have set charset=utf-8 but even then i'm not able to access the proper data with all the symbols. Is there anything I'm missing ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set database connection encoding:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

Or similar method, depending on your database library.

Comment: @fawad You need to use this not only for display purposes but also for insertion process. So this should work for newly inserted data.

Comment: I have called this function just above my insert function but still no result. :( Any other suggestion please ?

Comment: @fawad Have you saved your PHP file in UTF-8 using your code editor?

Comment: I'm not sure but i'm using Zend Studio. Do you think it stores file in utf-8 format ?

Comment: @fawad I don't know Zend Studio, but according to my knowledge Zend Studio is based on Eclipse. You need to open file properties and set the right encoding.

Comment: Should I set all files to UTF8 or ISO something?

Comment: @fawad Normally it's much easier to manage the code if all your files is saved in utf8. But keep in mind that charset conversion affects your old code too, so there is a possibility that something can stop working after the conversion. Also, keep in mind that you need to set HTML meta content-type to utf-8: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`. Managing right encodings is some kind of science :)

Comment: according to what "nobody" suggested i'm able to store proper symbol into the database but i can't get the proper symbol on html. What do you think now?

Comment: @fawad While nobody's solution should work, it's a little hackish. It's not the best way to manage encodings. But it's up to you. What do I think? I think you don't have HTML meta content-type set to utf8. Or perhaps you have HTTP header set to something other that utf8. Because HTTP headers overrides HTML meta tag if HTTP header is provided.

Comment: @karlis, you were right. My header was set to define('CHARSET', 'iso-8859-1');. Now I Have changed it to UTF-8 and it is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whats your MySQL server's default charset and collation? Try executing the following query before any other queries inside your scripts.

```
SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

BTW, are we talking about a MySQL server?

Comment: its for that table utf8_general_ci. How can I check the default charset? Its my MYSQL, phpmyadmin.

Comment: You can read it on the first page of PMA under `MySQL charset`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your column's charset is utf-8, then use this method for inserting:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES( 
    _utf8'After 30μs, what fraction of the charge will remain?', ...
);
```

and this for reading:

```
SELECT BINARY my_column FROM my_table;
```

Comment: Column is set to utf8_general_ci

Comment: @fawad good, now using the methods I mentioned should solve your problem.

Comment: After storing the data if i just access the data through phpmyadmin i get all unknown symbols. It means something has to be set with database. Am i right?

Comment: @fawad I'm not sure how much UTF-8 phpmyadmin supports and how does it represent UTF-8 data, don't rely on what phpmyadmin shows you. Make your own test code.

Comment: Actually, i'm storing all this data into database and then access it from database. What do you suggest now?