# PHP/or mysql messing up my insert

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [charset issue with mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972181/charset-issue-with-mysql)

So i have mysql string that has some of these characters in it:

,
?
“so”
‘so’
:
;
!
@
#
$
%
^
&
*
(
)
{
}
[
]
\
<
>
.
/
`
~
¨
°
¯
¡
¢
£
§
¸
´

When it is inserted into my database via the php command `mysql_query` some of the characters show up incorrectly. For instance, “so” becomes â€œsoâ€ However, when I print out the query and run it by hand in phpmyadmin, it works correctly. What is the correct way to insert these characters into the database so that they don't get all mangled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command before run your insert query:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Comment: I was just about to make a similar mention when I saw this one. I agree, its a character type issue. I'd say encode them maybe with entities or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure all those characters are escaped in PHP before you send them to MySQL. See this [mysql-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

That is only one example of a function that does it. I am sure there are other ones.